# How can I create a nested column by joining in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to perform a "join" on two Spark DataFrames (Scala), but instead of a SQL-like join, I'd like to insert the "joined" row from the second DataFrame as a single nested column in the first. The reason to do so is, ultimately, to write back out to JSON with a nested structure. I know the answer is likely already on Stackoverflow, but some searching has not turned up my answer.

Table 1

```
root
 |-- Insdc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastMetaUpdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Published: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Received: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ReplacedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- accession: string (nullable = true)
 |-- alias: string (nullable = true)
 |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- tag: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- center_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- design_description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geo_accession: string (nullable = true)
 |-- instrument_model: string (nullable = true)
 |-- library_construction_protocol: string (nullable = true)
 |-- library_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- library_selection: string (nullable = true)
 |-- library_source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- library_strategy: string (nullable = true)
 |-- paired: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- platform: string (nullable = true)
 |-- read_spec: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- base_coord: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- read_class: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- read_index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- read_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sample_accession: string (nullable = true)
 |-- spot_length: long (nullable = true)
 |-- study_accession: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

Table 2

```
root
 |-- BioProject: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Insdc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastMetaUpdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Published: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Received: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ReplacedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- abstract: string (nullable = true)
 |-- accession: string (nullable = true)
 |-- alias: string (nullable = true)
 |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- tag: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dbGaP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- external_id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- namespace: string (nullable = true)
 |-- submitter_id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- namespace: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

Join is on `table1.study_accession` with `table2.accession`. Result is below. Note the new column called `study` that contains record equivalents of Rows from table 2.

```
root
 |-- Insdc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastMetaUpdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Published: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Received: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ReplacedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- accession: string (nullable = true)
 |-- alias: string (nullable = true)
 |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- tag: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- center_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- design_description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geo_accession: string (nullable = true)
 |-- instrument_model: string (nullable = true)
 |-- library_construction_protocol: string (nullable = true)
 |-- library_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- library_selection: string (nullable = true)
 |-- library_source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- library_strategy: string (nullable = true)
 |-- paired: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- platform: string (nullable = true)
 |-- read_spec: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- base_coord: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- read_class: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- read_index: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- read_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sample_accession: string (nullable = true)
 |-- spot_length: long (nullable = true)
 |-- study_accession: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- accession: string (nullable = true)
 |-- study: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- BioProject: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Insdc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- LastMetaUpdate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- LastUpdate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Published: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Received: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ReplacedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- abstract: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- accession: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- alias: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- tag: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dbGaP: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- external_id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- namespace: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- submitter_id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- namespace: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: How about adding example input and expected output? Showing attempts would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my understanding to your question, lets say you have two dataframes

```
df1 
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col3: double (nullable = false)
```

and

```
df2
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: double (nullable = false)
```

You will have to combine all the columns of `df2` into a `struct` column and select the columns to be joined and the `struct` column. Here I am taking `col1` as the joining column

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val nestedDF2 = df2.select($"col1", struct(df2.columns.map(col):_*).as("nested_df2"))
```

Then final step is to `join` (here default is the `inner join`)

```
df1.join(nestedDF2, Seq("col1"))
```

which should give you

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col3: double (nullable = false)
 |-- nested_df2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col3: double (nullable = false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful